# Using doxygen to generate documentation for iOS Project

Tags: ios, doxygen-wizard

I am using Doxygen to create documentation for my iOS application. I followed the syntax specified by Doxygen to add documentation related to Class, methods, variables etc and completed the task for all the .h and .m files.

Now I'm using Doxygen tool to create html files. I am successfully generating the documentation using wizard, but it includes only comments from .h files only. Why is it not picking the .m files?

Do I have to include any arguments etc?

[Wizard File that I'm using](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/945659/PwdVault)

Comment: I've done with before without needing to do anything crazy. Do you have an error in your wizard setup?

Comment: @PaulCezanne Its not showing any error in Wizard. I too did it earlier, but now I'm facing this crazy error.

Comment: maybe share your wizard file with us?

Comment: @PaulCezanne I added the wizard file in my question.

Comment: hmmm, looks good to me but I'm not an expert. Say, you're not using .mm files, are you?

Comment: @PaulCezanne No .mm files

Comment: weird problem, wish I could help more. Good luck!